# asp.net fail to access value when set read-only to true

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

My update sql procedure is

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_update]

    @ID uniqueidentifier,
    @Period nvarchar(6),
   @News nvarchar(max),
   @Editor nvarchar(30)

     as
     begin

     update table1
   set      News= @News,  Editor=@Editor, LastRevNT=getdate()
    where ID=@ID and Period=@Period
       end
```

my asp.net grid view is

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
     <Columns>
      asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Period" HeaderText="Period" SortExpression="Period" ReadOnly="True"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="News" HeaderText="News" SortExpression="News" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Editor" HeaderText="Editor" SortExpression="Editor" ReadOnly="True" />
      </Columns>
```

datasource is

```
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="usp_select" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="usp_update" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="ID" SessionField="SelectedID" dbType="guid" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
          <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="ID" SessionField="SelectedID" dbType="guid" />
           <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="Editor" SessionField="SelectedEditor"  dbType="string"/>
         <asp:Parameter Name="Period" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="News" Type="String" />

     </UpdateParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Problem is that when I update the table, I need both ID and [Period] to get the unique record.
And in gridview, I don't want to [period] to be modified. When  I set  the bound for period to be read-only, then I fail to access the value of period, thus fail to update the right record.

I wonder how I can handle the problem?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: for taking id for update use the hiddenfield

Comment: I don't see the ID field in the grid.

Comment: Where's the Update command?

Comment: update command is the usp_update. Everything works fine if I remove "readonly =true" in the row for period. ID field comes from a session variable which comes from dropdownlist from master page

Comment: have you tried removing boundfield and use template for the period column?

Comment: @AJP Sorry, i don't know how to do that? do I simply replace boundfield with template?

Comment: <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderStyle />
                        <ItemStyle />
                        <ItemTemplate />
                    </asp:TemplateField> here is basic structure.

Answer (score 0):

I added DataKeyNames = "ID,Period" in my aspgridview, and it works ok now. Thanks for advice!